# What is the way around immutable strings in JAVA?

Tags: java, string

I am working on a small problem. I know that StringBuilder class is used in JAVA to work on mutable strings. The problem I am working on requires me to pass a string to a function that returns void and reverses the String in place. I somehow cannot get that done because the string I am referring to after the function call in main is no longer the string I have sent as an argument to the function. Is there a way I can get that String without having to return?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class first {
void rev(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length()+1);
    sb.append(s);
    sb.reverse();
    System.out.println(sb);
    s=sb.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String s;
    first fs = new first();
    s=br.readLine();
    fs.rev(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}
}
```

Comment: *The problem I am working on requires me to pass a string to a function that returns void and reverses the String in place.* That is **not** possible in Java.

Comment: Also, trivially your `rev()` method is using `StringBuilder#reverse`, so why not just call it once for the final answer?  I think they are looking for some other implementation.

Comment: If someone told your that your method had to be `void rev(String s)`, then they sent you on a [fool's errand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fool%27s_errand).

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: If you set s to an instance variable that you can reference from main after you make the call to rev(), but that's not really the correct answer to the problem.

Comment: Are you allowed to use reflection?  See [this post](http://www.javacreed.com/how-to-modify-a-string-without-creating-a-new-one/) and never, ever do this in a non-school project.

Comment: The real answer: you've probably misunderstood the requirements. Go get clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass by StringBuilder instead of String like this.

```
void rev(StringBuilder sb) {
    sb.reverse();
    System.out.println(sb);
    String s = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    Main fs = new Main();
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(br.readLine());
    fs.rev(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Java is pass by value, so that cannot be done. However, you can hack it by having a member variable that holds the string (and just manipulate that)

Comment: Exactly, why are you recommending a wrapper class when if he had flexibility on parameters, he'd best use a StringBuilder?

Comment: @Vasan Actually, it does have to do with pass-by-value. If the language were pass-by-reference, it would be doable since you could just assign the calling function's local variable to the reversed string. It's the *combination* of immutability and strict pass-by-value that makes it impossible. This answer's hack isn't good, but it's not wrong that pass-by-value is important here.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're right. I was thinking from the angle of "even with pass-by-value it's doable (using StringBuilder or similar) so it's not a pass-by-value problem". But I didn't think of the "if pass-by-reference _was_ available" angle. Deleted my comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels this person is already using a wrapper class. I'm just suggesting a hack based on what they are already doing with the parameters given. Obviously the answer should be that this person should not be trying to do this at all.